# Local Block as a part of the ContentArea

Tags: c#, properties, block, episerver, episerver-7

**Preambula**

```
[ContentType(...)]
public abstract class _BaseSitePage : PageData { ... }

[ContentType(...)]
public abstract class _ContentPage : _BaseSitePage
{
    [Display(Name = "Content 1", GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content, Order = 4)]
    public virtual ContentArea Content1 { get; set; }  
}

public abstract class _FixedBodyLayoutPage : _ContentPage
{
    [Display(Name = "Body", GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content, Order = 100)]
    public virtual ThreeColumnRowBlock Body{ get; set; }
}
```

During creating the instance of the `_FixedBodyLayoutPage` I want to place instance of the local block `ThreeColumnRowBlock` inside the `Content1` as a predefined block.
Also I want to show on edit pages Only properties of the `ThreeColumnRowBlock` instance and hide the `Content1`.

```
[Editable(false), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public override ContentArea Content1
{
  get { return this.GetPropertyValue(x => base.Content1); }
  set { this.SetPropertyValue(x => base.Content1, value); }
}
```

The problem is: I cannot find any suitable way to register instance of the `ThreeColumnRowBlock` inside the Content1 content area. API requires ContentReference, but from what i see local blocks does not have it.

**Partly found solution:**
instead of local block can be used shared blocks.

But then I loose ability to edit there properties on edit pages without deep navigation. Which i want to avoid a lot. All those nesting is breaking the concept of CMS, be more concentrated on content instead of hierarchy of objects.

Is it possible to somehow bind local block to shared block? or force episerver to display shared block properties inside the page editors?

I also try to implement get/set which extracts instance of the shared block and returns it instead of local block. But that does not trick the episerver. Edit pages displays data from wrong instance.

Comment: Why do you want the ThreeColumnRowBlock to be part of the ContentArea?  Why not just have it be a local block on the page and render your ContentArea below it?

Comment: If you are on 7.5 or newer, take a look at http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-CMS/75/Rendering/Display-options/Display-options/

Comment: Idea is to make editing of the page simple as possible and with minimal re-navigation (clicks) to other content pages. Very easy to lose context.


I think it is possible to use shared blocks instead of local for simplifying the page editor behaviour. Local blocks will represent easy to understand abstractions, but on lower level everything will be stored as a sub-blocks of the one ContentArea property.

Comment: in any case, I try to push the bounds of the episerver... highly possible this is wrong approach